# How to get access the method from other method of class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I want to calculate the density of box (volume). I calculated volume of box, but I couldn't calculated density of box.

```
import java.util.*;
     class DimBox{
        int width;
        int depth;
        int height;
        int s;
            DimBox(int width,int depth,int height){
            this.width=width;
            this.height=height;
            this.depth=depth;
        }
            int getDimBox(){
            int s= width*depth*height;
            return s;
        }
     }
     class DensityBox{
        int density;
        int getDimBox;
        int getWeightBox();
            int getDensity(int density){
            density = getDimBox * getWeightBox();
            return density;
        }
     }
     class WeightBox{
        int weight;
            WeightBox(int weight){
            this.weight=weight;
        }
        int getWeightBox(){
            return weight;
        }
         }
     public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
        DimBox dimBox=new DimBox(20,50,30);
        System.out.println(dimBox.getDimBox());
        WeightBox weightBox=new WeightBox(75);
        DensityBox densityBox=new DensityBox();
        System.out.println(densityBox.density);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please put your code and show what you have done up to now.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: My code at the top

Comment: Does this code even compile? ```int getWeightBox();``` has no method body and this is not an abstract class either. Terrible code as well. Zero OOP.  If you wish to call a method do it like this ```System.out.println(densityBox.getDensity());``` and make sure the getter has no input params cause it makes no sense for a getter of such scenario to have such params

Comment: Thank you, but I know it. Just forgot to write ().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted something like :

```
class DensityBox{

    float weight, volume;

    DensityBox(float weight, float volume){
        this.weight = weight; // check >0
        this.volume = volume; //check >=0
    }

    float getDensity() {  return volume/weight;   }
 }
```

and use it :

```
DensityBox densityBox = new DensityBox(weightBox.getWeightBox(), dimBox.getDimBox());
float density = densityBox.getDensity();
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: *I haven’t given direct code as giving direct code wouldn’t help you understand the basics and will face lot of difficulties later.*

This can be solved in many different ways.

One option is Composition, DensityBox should have DimBox instance and Weight instance variable to access their methods.

Either during constructing DensityBox instance or later using setters on DensityBox instance, set DimBox and Weight instances inside DensityBox instance so that their member methods can be accessed.

Another option would be to use static helper methods that have objects of different classes as parameters to do the dirty work.

One more option will be calling methods from all the classes in main method to do the desired calculation in main method itself. But I wouldn’t recommend this one as it doesn’t demonstrate OOP, this is just FYI.

You need to go back to basics to understand basic OOP concepts and understand composition of objects or how to use static helper methods that has objects passed to it to do the dirty work.

Comment: Thank you very much JRG. Best answer! I want to tick your answer, but I couldn't it.

Comment: As you have already chosen another answer :), vote up if you liked it!

Comment: @Iwantask I did it for you (0: